# How to make a series of SPAN tags into a flex-box that evenly uses 100% width?

Tags: css, flexbox

I currently have:

[image: item]

Each of the circles is inside a span. How can I use flexbox so that the 3 circle spans take up 100% with of the parent DIV and are evenly spaced out?

Given: https://jsfiddle.net/humt9cs4/3/

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Item</label>
    <div class="rate-mod"><span name="skill_id_1" value=""><span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;"><span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></span><span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"><span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span></span>
        </span><span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;"><span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></span><span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"><span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span></span>
        </span><span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;"><span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></span><span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"><span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span></span>
        </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.rate-mod {
  border: 1px solid #E0E6F1;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ED5351, #EDAB51, #00C644);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row!important;

  span span {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background: red;
  }

}
```

Comment: note I've tired to get the flexbox working but it isn't taking, what am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the flex css to `<span name="skill_id_1">` and re-organize your SCSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/humt9cs4/4/

And here's the compiled output.

```css
.rate-mod [name="skill_id_1"] {
  border: 1px solid #E0E6F1;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ED5351, #EDAB51, #00C644);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ED5351, #EDAB51, #00C644);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ED5351, #EDAB51, #00C644);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ED5351, #EDAB51, #00C644);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row !important;
}
.rate-mod span span {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Item</label>
  <div class="rate-mod"><span name="skill_id_1" value=""><span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;"><span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></span>
    <span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"><span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span></span>
    </span><span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;"><span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></span><span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"><span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span></span>
    </span><span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: relative;"><span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></span><span style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0%;"><span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 50%; border: 5px double white; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: black;"></span></span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```